# TLS Connection - Beats to Redis

Tags: ssl, redis, filebeat

I have Winlogbeat installed on a Windows box using Redis output.

The Redis server is configured for TLS on port 6380.

Both ends start services up successfully but the connection does not succeed.  I have tried different combinations of protocols and cipher suites but no luck.  What am I missing?  The error messages:

```
Redis:
Error accepting a client connection: error:1408A0C1:SSL routines:ssl3_get_client_hello:no shared cipher

Windows:
ERROR   [publisher_pipeline_output] pipeline/output.go:154  Failed to connect to redis(tcp://10.1.1.4:6380): remote error: tls: handshake failure
```

Here is the redis-server config.  The CA is self-signed, 2048-bit key and x509 certificate.  The server certificate is also x509.  I think I may need to rebuild the CA, but feedback is appreciated on this.

```
#tls configs
tls-port 6380
tls-cert-file /etc/ssl/redis.crt 
tls-key-file /etc/ssl/private/redis.key
tls-ca-cert-file /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ca.crt
tls-auth-clients no
tls-prefer-server-ciphers no
tls-protocols "TLSv1.2"
tls-dh-params-file /etc/ssl/redis.dh
tls-ciphers DEFAULT
tls-ciphersuites ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305
```

And the Beats config.

```
output.redis:
  hosts: ["10.1.1.4:6380"]
  password: "redispass"
  key: "winlogbeat"
  db: 0
  timeout: 5
  data_type: "list"
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    certificate_authorities: ["C:\\Program Data\\Winlogbeat\\ca.crt"]
    insecure: true
    supported_protocols: [TLSv1.2]
    cipher_suites: [ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305]
    curve_types: [P-256]
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally worked it out, in case anyone is interested.

Needed to install and configure the CA with proper params, and then create a SAN server certificate for Redis using IP addresses and a hostname.  Here are the articles I followed.

On the server that hosts Redis, create the root CA: https://blog.devolutions.net/2020/07/tutorial-how-to-generate-secure-self-signed-server-and-client-certificates-with-openssl (just the root CA from this article).

Create the Redis server certificate using IP address subject alternative names: https://www.golinuxcloud.com/openssl-generate-csr-create-san-certificate/

Install Redis from source with TLS support: https://godfrey-tutu.medium.com/redis-6-deployment-with-tls-authentication-on-centos-7-8b6e34d11cd0

Beats and Redis will negotiate best encryption.  If you keep the existing Redis config and add the TLS piece on a different unused port, then Redis will start up and listen on both.

Here is the new Beat config:

```
output.redis:
  hosts: ["10.1.1.4:6380"]
  password: "redispass"
  key: "winlogbeat"
  db: 0
  timeout: 5
  data_type: "list"
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    certificate_authorities: ["C:\\Program Data\\Winlogbeat\\ca.crt"]
    insecure: true
    supported_protocols: [TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]
```

And Redis...

```
tls-port 6380
tls-cert-file /etc/pki/tls/certs/redis.crt
tls-key-file /etc/pki/tls/private/redis.key
tls-ca-cert-file /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.crt
tls-auth-clients no
tls-protocols "TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2"
tls-prefer-server-ciphers yes
```

Comment: So basically you configured redis to accept connections with auth being TLS handshake using x509 certs? Very cool 